# lldb breakpoint set command fails

Tags: xcode, xcode8, breakpoints, lldb

I am attempting to use `lldb`'s programmatic breakpoint setting.  The command is:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -r . -s <product-name>
Breakpoint 25: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

As you can see, it throws me a warning saying it can't resolve the locations for a breakpoint.  I'm running my project with a debug scheme and no optimization.

What might be causing this warning?

Answer (score 0):

If `<product-name>` is a shared library, it might not be loaded yet.  Use:

```
(lldb) image list <product-name>
```

to verify.  If that's the case, don't worry, lldb will resolve the breakpoint when the library gets loaded.

You might also have a different spelling of `<product-name>` than lldb, for instance the module name for MyApp.app is actually "MyApp".  Try setting a breakpoint on a name you know is in `<product-name>` then do `break list` and the output will have:

```
1.1 where = ModuleName`symbol_name...
```

ModuleName is what you want to pass to -s.

Note, if a breakpoint on a symbol name you know is present doesn't resolve to any locations, then you might be stripping the binary before debugging.  You can verify this by finding the binary (`image list` will tell you this as well) and in Terminal, run:

```
$ nm -ap <PathToBinary>
```

if you don't see any output here, then the binary is getting stripped.  You need to figure out whose doing that and get them to stop...

Answer (score 0):

Uh, looks like your search for a function

> .

which will not be found would be my guess.

In the olden Macsbug days, the dot stood for current PC but that won't work in lldb.